# Compound formed from concentrated sulfuric acid and sulfur

Tags: reaction-mechanism, ions, raman

In the reaction below, I know what **A** and **B** are, but I'm not sure what compound **C** is.

All I know about it is the following:

- Deep yellow solid
- Dication contains only sulfur
- Raman and infra-red spectra of the dication show no common features

I think that the dication might be $\ce{[S4]^{2+}}$ since I think that this would be square planar and therefore have $D_{\mathrm{4h}}$ symmetry, which has no irreps that are both Raman and IR active, but I don't know what the anion would be.

The other likely options for the sulfur dication would be $\ce{[S8]^{2+}}$ or $\ce{[S19]^{2+}}$ but I think the fact that it's yellow would make it $\ce{[S4]^{2+}}$.

[image: Reaction]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reaction is given [here](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-952).

$$\ce{S + 2H2SO4 → 3SO2 + 2H2O}$$

Sulfur react with sulfuric acid to produce sulfur dioxide and water. Sulfuric acid should be concentrated solution. The reaction takes place in a boiling solution.

$\ce{[S4]^2+}$, $\ce{[S8]^2+}$ or $\ce{[S19]^2+}$ is formed when sulfur is dissolved in oleum. The following is a paraphrase of an [inorganic textbook](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Mtth5g59dEIC&pg=PA517&lpg=PA517&dq=sulfur%20cation&source=bl&ots=tE_JlzL_NE&sig=rSyV-ktub7iWjj5Mi0BrQfkWgHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3k_uU_K7MAhWOc44KHYpPBSsQ6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=sulfur%20cation&f=false).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The yellow species is indeed the $\ce{S4^{2+}}$ cation, as reportrd by Nilay Ghosh's reference. Its relative stability and symmetric structure, amenable to delocalization of electrons, goes along with [an inorganic version of aromaticity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/98973/17175).

The counterion in the sulfuric acid medium would surely be leveled to bisulfate ion, $\ce{HSO4^-}$. The number of bisulfate ions is actually more than twice the number of $\ce{S4^{2+}}$ ions because the reduction process of concentrated sulfuric acid inherently generates more $\ce{HSO4^-}$ ions, and $\ce{H3O^+}$ ions, along with the acid reduction product. If we make the likely simplifying assumption that the acid which is reduced forms sulfur dioxide, we may render the reaction

$\ce{4S + 5H2SO4 -> S4^{2+} + SO2(g) + 4HSO4^- + 2H3O^+}$